# AngularJS Disable Adding Slashes To HashTags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS is automatically adding slashes to hashtags

```
http://www.example.com/users#top
```

becmomes

```
http://www.example.com/users#/top
```

I do not want use ng-route for routing nor do I want it adding slashes to hashtags. How can I disable this?

Comment: read [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location), how is it relocating if you dont have angular-route added to the page?

Comment: Its not relocating and I don't want it to. I just want to disable the hashes

Comment: I just added angular to a Plunker, and I did a link to a div that was off the page, the link took me to the div, no routing or anything..

Comment: You may want to add more code so that we don't keep stabbing at the dark